# Getting no errors using mail() in PHP

Tags: php, email

When in PHP I am using the `mail()` function incorrectly I do not get an error as return value:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(mail(1,2,3))
  echo 'true';
else
  echo 'false';
```

The above delivers no PHP error and the echo is `true`.

So it seems the "mail" with the obviously wrong parameters has been accepted: "[Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)" (php.net).

Only when I change the third line to

```
if(mail(1,2))
```

I get a PHP warning and the string `false` is printed.

The above two cases have the same result on either a server with no mail-server installed at all or a server with a correctly working mail-server. Is that "works as designed" or am I misusing/misunderstanding the return value of the mail()-function?

If it is "works as designed" **is there any deeper reason for checking the return value?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mail()` returns true if the server has accepted the mail for the delivery. It does not mean the email to be sent is valid or will ever be delivered. It just literally means *the server has accepted the mail for the delivery*. That's why you see questions every day about how `mail()` isn't working because it returned `true` but mail was never received. The `true` value does not mean delivery or even anything is valid. It just means the server accepted the request to send an email.

Comment: "The true value does not mean delivery or even anything is valid."

So if my example request is accepted even though it is definitivly wrong - is there any situation where it makes sense to check the return value of the mail()-function?

Comment: @Wooz To determine if the mailing server accepted the mail or not. If it's accepted the mail request, and you've properly validated the fields beforehand, you can make the safe assumption that it will in fact send. Failure indicates a problem with your parameters, or the mailing server itself.

Comment: Yes but mostly when receiving a false value. In that case you know there was an error getting the email to the server and you know what to troubleshoot. A response of true isn't very helpful in debugging as there are a lot of potential points of failure that still need to be investigated. But at least it does eliminate one potential cause.

Comment: So the return value mainly is for checking whether the general communication between php and mailserver worked?? (And in addition a failure in case of to few params..)

Comment: That about sums it up.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are even asking:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Bare minimum is 3 arguments.

Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: *Not sure what you are even asking* Then how can you answer the question if you don't know what  the question is?

Comment: Yes, thats clear so far... But the php.net description also says (eg. for param **$to**: "The formatting of this string **must comply with RFC 2822.**" which I obviously fail in my example request. 

So if my example request is accepted even though it is definitivly wrong - is there any situation where it makes sense to check the return value of the mail()-function?

Comment: @Rizier123 it isn't clear what he/she is specifically looking for, just general questions that he/she found an answer to already

Answer (score 0):

@Woox the mail() function allows you to send a mail from your php website (even if you don't have a mail-server)

Everything is well explained here:
www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't have problems sending mails. I just can't 100% figure out the return value of the mail()-function - it delivers "true" in cases the mail would obviosly fail (as in my example).

Comment: @Wooz you should set the correct param and not just 1,2,3.. if everything is correct you will display "true", otherwise "false"

Comment: Well, not really. You get "true" also with 1,2,3 - and that actually was the problem I had. I wanted to know **why** I get true with wrong params and what sense the return value makes then. When I use correct params I don't have any problems at all, but that was not the question I had... but I think I have the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra explanation to go with @JohnConde's answer, since they explained the *how*, but not the *why*.

`mail()` assumes nothing about the parameters it's given.

`mail(1,2,3)` is going to pass along an e-mail address  of `1`, a subject of `2`, and a message of `3`. Obviously the e-mail address is invalid, but `mail()` doesn't care, that's for the mailing server to deal with.

`mail(1,2)` is missing a message. Mailing server won't accept this.

Comment: So you say the return value is simply checking if the param count is valid by the mail server? Or is the return value already the "answer from the mail server", so **true** meaning the mail server has been contacted successfully (and it has not brusquely returned the request due to wrong param count... )

Comment: `true` means the mailing server accepted the mail, and will probably try to send it - doesn't mean the mail's been sent, and it doesn't mean the fields are valid. `false` means the mailing server didn't accept the mail (missing field, server unresponsive, etc.). That's really all there is to it. John's answer explained this already.

Comment: Thank you very much. I marked Johns answer the useful one but actually I got the clue of the combination of what John and what you wrote... unfortunally I am not yet allowed to mark your answer as useful.